# How to return to "the mad God's bargain" mission

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I left the mission because even though it said it was a lvl 32 quest, the enemies were lvl 43 and a bit out of my league, but now that I have leveled up I can't find how to return to it. Does anyone know how to find this quest again?

Answer (score 1):

The guild missions, and the main story mission are always your level, and so are the rewards. The mobs though have a minimum level, and that's why they were 43.

To reenter you can do one of the following:

1. Go to mage guild where you started the mission (depends on race, is the last town - level wise). Inside you should find a portal (usually in the middle of the biggest room).
2. You could reset the quest, and start over.